# AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() not working on Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-7.0-nougat

Today I got a report from users running Android Nougat that headphones aren't being detected by my app. This feature is already working fine for previous Android versions. Is there anyone else who faced the same issue?

I am still using the deprecated AudioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn() method and I hadn't added MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission in Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [long standing bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20765). You will always get `false` when calling `isWiredHeadsetOn` unless your add `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: I think this permission is no longer needed because I've been using this method since long and it's working fine. The issue started appearing in Android Nougat today.